# Scriptsharp 0.7 Ajaxcallback breaking change, how to convert to Ajaxcallback<TData>?

Tags: script#

I just converted scriptsharp project from 0.6 to 0.7: compiler complains on AjaxCallback, has become AjaxCallback<TData>  Which type should I use for TData ?

Also how to translate this:

```
new Dictionary(
   "autoOpen", false,
   "buttons", new Dictionary("Ok",(Callback) delegate() { jQuery.This.Cast<JQDialog>().dialog("close"); }),
"title", "my title",
     "close", (Callback)delegate() { jQuery.Select("#summary-ul").Empty(); })
                                           );
```

**Callback** does not exist anymore, replace with?

**Update**: I also get following warning: Warning   1   The predefined type 'System.Action' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Program Files (x86)\ScriptSharp\v1.0\Framework\mscorlib.dll'
even though I changed all references to ScriptSharp dir. Do I need to change somewhere else?

**Update 2** : apparently Callback can be replaced by Action, that one is solved
but I still get compile errors:

```
        Error 15    The type 'System.Action' exists in both 
    'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll' 
and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\ScriptSharp\v1.0\Framework\mscorlib.dll'
    C:\Projects\VS2010\Net4\MvcScriptSharp\src\Framework\UIMasterDetail.cs  519 52
```

Where does that reference to System.Core come from? Can't find it in csproj file...

**Update 3**: changing target framework from 3.5 to 4.0 solved the issue with type conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For answers see update 2 and update 3